# How do I help myself to learn JMS?

Tags: jms

I want to understand the fundamental concepts of JMS by developing my own simple application. I spent a little time on a couple of tutorials but it didn't help me to understand how the messaging works.

What do I need to build my own program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing you need to build your own JMS application is a message broker which provides a JMS client implementation.

[ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/) is a fine place to start. [Download it](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/download.html) and take a look at the examples in the `examples/` directory. Start with something basic like the `queue` example (in the `examples/features/standard/queue` directory). You can run the example by executing the command `mvn verify` in the example's directory. It will start a broker and run the client code. You can look at the code and change it however you want and run it again. This will allow you to experiment easily and learn by example.